# On what can the code base the detection of his current configuration (Test/QA/Prod)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-deployment

I want the deployment to be error proof regarding connection string, settings and so on. On which parameter can the App make the test to determine at startup where it is running. Is System.Environment.MachineName a bad idea? Is there a common way to do this?

What I'm trying to address is the fact that the web.config file is merged with the source code during each merging. So I can not have a special web.config for each kind of deployment.

My ideas was to have the 3 settings in the original web.config. The application will be able to detect and figure out where it runs and make a cherry picking amongst the 3 app settings, 3 connection strings that fits the current running environment...

Comment: Have you looked into Web.config transforms in VS2010 and above?

Comment: @JohnSaunders : It's seems to be the way to go indeed. But, It doesn't work for testing on localhost, isn't it? What is the trick to have it work on publish and also on localhost?

Comment: Put the localhost configuration right in web.config. The transforms are then for the different environments and configurations. In VS2012, they've split it so you can have one set of transforms for the build config (Debug, Release), and one for each environment (Integration, QA, UAT, Production).

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Ok, but how do you test the 3 config on localhost? I don't want to change the main web.config each time...

Comment: @JohnSaunders: you should transmute your comment to an answer, because you're the closest one until now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a good idea, you should separate your enviroments in the first place. The p can't access the test and qa enviroments (and vica versa). As result your application will not work put the wrong configuration file on p. This has the same result as your check on machine name, and configuration settings. If you change your production machine for any reason you have to recompile your code, and a whole test cycle is needed to check if all is fine. This would be expensive and time consuming.